# shutil copy issue

Tags: python

So I have the following script

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy, os
import fnmatch
import shutil
import zipfile

zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('MXD_DC.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Y:\Data\MXD_DC"):
       for file in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))

 shutil.copy(r'MXD_DC.zip', 'D:/')
```

After copying the file over to d drive when I try to unzip it, the error is "Before you can extract files, you must copy files to this compressed zipped folder". I can take the original zip file from the other drive and unzip it just fine. I can manually copy it over to d drive and unzip it just fine. It happens only when I use shutil to copy to the d drive.

Comment: It's often a good idea to use `copy2()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2

Comment: Patrick I was using that initially and then switched to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the zipfile before you go to copy it. Either `zipf.close()` before the `shutil.copy` or

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('MXD_DC.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Y:\Data\MXD_DC"):
        for file in files:
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))

shutil.copy2('MXD_DC.zip','D:/')
```

You could also use `shutil.copy2` again.